# Where is the session timeout setting for Content Author and Administrator in Sitecore 9.2?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

I am having trouble accessing CM on Sitecore 9.2 (built on Azure PaaS) without getting a session timeout.

I have the following settings, but if I leave the browser open for more than 20 minutes with the launchpad displayed, and then click any button
After that, when I click on some button, I expected to be forcibly logged out, but
I expected that the session timeout would occur when I left the system for more than 20 minutes without logging out, and then clicked some button.

Please let me know if there is a way to force a session timeout logout.

Configuration details

(1) Web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement. CoditionalSessionIdManager">
```

(2) Sitecore

```
<setting name="Authentication.ClientSessionTimeout" value="20" />
```

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue with Sitecore 9.3. You can try below solution if it works.

Set ExpireTimeSpanin Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config which is given below for bow "PreviewCookieAuthentication" and "CookieAuthentication".
00:20:00

Then Set  in sitecore.config.

It should work for 20 minutes. I am facing issue when I increase timeout value from 20 to 30 minute.